# Case Statements in group by, Why doesn't this work? Dynamic Aggregation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a query which aggregates some data by one of several columns. (Only ever expecting one, but very interested in hearing multi solutions too!).

I've created the following query but it doesn't work. It complains that all the columns

> is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I'm very interested in hearing why this is the case, as when the query is run the correct column would always be grouped. Obviously I'm also interested in solutions to my problem too, but will press on with figuring it out myself.

```
Declare @AggregateColumn int = 1

SELECT
    ResultID,
    CASE
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 1 THEN Col1
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 2 THEN Col2
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 3 THEN Col3
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 4 THEN Col4
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 5 THEN Col5
        ELSE 'ERROR'
    END AS ResultName,
    SUM(a.ResultValue) AS ResultValue
FROM
    #Results
GROUP BY
    ResultID,
    CASE
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 1 THEN Col1
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 2 THEN Col2
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 3 THEN Col3
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 4 THEN Col4
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 5 THEN Col5
        ELSE null
    END
```

Thank you for your time.

Edit: Thanks for the responses... I'd added an extra typo to my question. Basically I've fixed this issue myself. SQL returns very unhelpful error messages if you've done what I've done above. Namely Else 'ERROR' needs to be else null. You'd never realise that was the problem though from the error message SQL gives!

Comment: Remove the `AS ResultName` in the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the alias in the group by:

```
GROUP BY
    ResultID,
CASE
    WHEN @AggregateColumn = 1 THEN Col1
    WHEN @AggregateColumn = 2 THEN Col2
    WHEN @AggregateColumn = 3 THEN Col3
    WHEN @AggregateColumn = 4 THEN Col4
    WHEN @AggregateColumn = 5 THEN Col5
    ELSE null
END -- AS ResultName
```

Comment: I stupidly inserted that error myself when I was copying out my code to put in here.

I figured out my issue myself... It was more or less another typo.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I've fixed this issue myself. SQL returns very unhelpful error messages if you've done what I've done.

Namely Else 'ERROR' needs to be else null. You'd never realise that was the problem though from the error message SQL gives! It complains about all the other columns.

```
Declare @AggregateColumn int = 1

SELECT
    ResultID,
    CASE
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 1 THEN Col1
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 2 THEN Col2
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 3 THEN Col3
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 4 THEN Col4
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 5 THEN Col5
        ELSE null
    END AS ResultName,
    SUM(a.ResultValue) AS ResultValue
FROM
    #Results
GROUP BY
    ResultID,
    CASE
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 1 THEN Col1
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 2 THEN Col2
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 3 THEN Col3
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 4 THEN Col4
        WHEN @AggregateColumn = 5 THEN Col5
        ELSE null
    END
```